# How to convert DateTime to VarChar(50)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, converters

I need to convert DateTime value to Varchar value in 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt' format.

Please resolve.
Datetime format: 2013-12-13 23:10:56.000
Varchar format: 26/10/2013 08:36:44 PM

Comment: Do you want to change dataType of column or you just want to display dateTime in preferred format.?

Comment: If the column is meant to store a date and time value, keep it as a `datetime`. Don't let *formatting* concerns change how you store the *data*. Do the formatting, as required, when you *present* the data to the user.

Comment: @user3244104 I suspect you do not want to convert the column if it is a date then should be a date column (I have spent many hours dealing with dates in varchar columns and it is not fun and leads to many bugs)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want that output, googling "sql server datetime format" will reveal [this link](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/). If you want to alter the column itself, you have two options:

1. Alter it directly, then update it and fix the format afterwards.
   OR
2. Add a new column of the type `varchar(20)`. Move data from old DATETIME column, remove the old column. If needed rename the new column.

Comment: And just to point out, the comments below your post are absolutely correct. Typically your DB should store the pure data in the intended (ie. DATETIME) format. Let UI, code etc, or just your SELECT to worry about proper formatting. There are numerous reasons for this, from indexes and performance to filter and function usage to data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),GETDATE(),130)